# Floppy drive doesn't turn on or make noise when dding an image to it?

Tags: dd, floppy

So I used `dd` to write a `.img` file to a floppy disk. The command completed instantly, and the floppy drive didn't turn on or make any noise. I'm sure that I specified the correct block device, so what happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the `.img` file was only 1.44MB, it was written entirely into the RAM cache without any of it being actually written to the floppy.

After running the `dd` command, you'll want to run this command to ensure that the FS cache has been written to disk:

```
sync
```

After running the above command, the floppy drive came alive and wrote the cached data to the floppy.